# I created a SQL query to INSERT INTO and keep gettting -Msg 102- Incorrect syntax near ','

Tags: sql-insert, new-operator

I copied the table structure of Patient P to new table PatientF F. I want to use Patient P and insert rows where the PATID in Patientf F= Patient P.

Here is a shortened example of the query.

```
INSERT INTO PATIENTF (PGID, P.PATID, PREFERREDPRONOUNS) 
    SELECT (PGID, P.PATID, PREFERREDPRONOUNS)
    FROM PATIENT P
    LEFT JOIN PATIENTF F ON F.PATID = P.PATID
    WHERE F.PATID = P.PATID
```

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Your list of columns should include "PATID" not "P.PATID", it's the column names to be updated in the target table, not the column references from the SELECT clause

Comment: Also you don't need to do the comparison in the WHERE clause, you've already done it in the join

Comment: thank you, that did clear out the error.  Now I am seeing it here SELECT (PGID,  I took out the p.patid and then put it back in and still get the error in the select section

Comment: OK you **need** P.PATID in the `SELECT` because you have to disambiuguate (even though because of the predicate the value is the same in both tables).

Answer (score 0):

As the comments suggest, the issue is with the P.PATID in the INSERT command, i.e. this bit:

```
INSERT INTO PATIENTF (PGID, P.PATID, PREFERREDPRONOUNS)
```

The INSERT command expects a list of column names here, and the column name in your PATIENTF table is PATID, not P.PATID.  With that in mind, the corrected line above would be:

```
INSERT INTO PATIENTF (PGID, PATID, PREFERREDPRONOUNS)
```

Now, onto the second part, the SELECT statement that is "getting" the data to INSERT, what you have is as follows:

```
SELECT (PGID, P.PATID, PREFERREDPRONOUNS)
    FROM PATIENT P
    LEFT JOIN PATIENTF F ON F.PATID = P.PATID
    WHERE F.PATID = P.PATID
```

The first thing I notice (and it's mentioned in the comments above) is that the WHERE clause is not needed, so we can simplify to:

```
SELECT (PGID, P.PATID, PREFERREDPRONOUNS)
    FROM PATIENT P
    LEFT JOIN PATIENTF F ON F.PATID = P.PATID
```

Now, on MSSQL the second column name here would just default to PATID, so your row would be returned with the following columns:

```
<PGID, PATID, PREFERREDPRONOUNS>
```

However, I like to be precise so I would tend to do the following:

```
SELECT (PGID, P.PATID AS 'PATID', PREFERREDPRONOUNS)
    FROM PATIENT P
    LEFT JOIN PATIENTF F ON F.PATID = P.PATID
```

So I know that I am getting the row:

```
<PGID, PATID, PREFERREDPRONOUNS>
```

*NOTE: I am ASSUMING MSSQL here, others DB systems might be different....

So, putting it all together, the correct SQL for your INSERT command would be:

```
INSERT INTO PATIENTF (PGID, PATID, PREFERREDPRONOUNS) 
    SELECT (PGID, P.PATID AS 'PATID', PREFERREDPRONOUNS)
    FROM PATIENT P
    LEFT JOIN PATIENTF F ON F.PATID = P.PATID
```